# How can this be an audit?

Tags: discussion, specific-audit

I just stumbled upon [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68545897/install-rakudo-on-termux-android) while reviewing the triage.

My judgement was: "Don't post text as images.", but apparently it was an audit. Please, even while the images are clear, this should not be an audit.

Comment: Because bad audits exist. Though *how* that question has *8* upvotes in less than a month seems suspicious to me. Downvote the source, move on. It'll stop being an audit of a "good" question once it receives enough.

Comment: @Larnu: the problem is that my preview priviledges have been suspended, amongst other because of questionnable audits.

Comment: You failed [this audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/29578418) too though. Had you passed that, you'd be fine. You don't get queue banned for just *one* failed audit or bad review, but many. There are others you have failed too.

Comment: It's closed and has downvotes now so it will no longer be an audit. If the OP converts the images to text it could potentially be reopened.

Comment: @RobertLongson: thanks for that. In the meantime my review privileges have been suspended, amongst others because of that audit (which now is not an audit anymore). Can my review privileges be "unsuspended" or do I need to write a new question for that?

Comment: A moderator might stop by and do that but I wouldn't hold your breath as they will look at all your audit failures and you appear to have made some mistakes so It wouldn't surprise me if they left your suspension as it is so you can consider those.

Comment: To be honest, I don't even think it's on topic if the OP posted the Shell's output as text, @RobertLongson . The question is about installation, which isn't normally on topic for [so].

Comment: @Larnu questions about software tools are on-topic and this is installing a Perl compiler. It hardly seems like a SU territory. With that said, it does need a lot more details. The "second try" screenshot doesn't even show what the try *is*, just the end of the output messages.

Comment: @Larnu: Installing a compiler is on-topic. It's covered by "software tools commonly used by programmers"